# Exception in finetuning after a few epochs in Keras with Tensorflow backend (about epoch 5 to 10)

Tags: tensorflow, keras

Finetuning is stopped after a few epochs. Mostly in epoch 5 or 8. The number of last epoch is different in different runs.

**Error:**

```
File "/opt/keras-python3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/PIL/JpegImagePlugin.py", line 126, in APP
    dpi = x_resolution[0] / x_resolution[1]
    ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

**My configurations:**

1. Tensorflow 1.0.1
2. Keres 2.0.3
3. Kubuntu 14.04
4. Python 3.4

What is the problem? Why it occurs after a few epoch not in the first one?
Is it possible one corrupted image file makes this problem? Why in the first epoch it didn't happened?

**Code:**

```
from keras.applications.inception_v3 import InceptionV3
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Dense, GlobalAveragePooling2D
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint, TensorBoard, CSVLogger, Callback
from keras.optimizers import SGD

# create the base pre-trained model
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

base_model = InceptionV3(weights='imagenet', include_top=False)

# add a global spatial average pooling layer
x = base_model.output
x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
# let's add a fully-connected layer

x = Dense(1024, activation='relu')(x)


# and a logistic layer -- let's say we have 2 classes
# predictions = Dense(1, activation='softmax')(x) #A
predictions = Dense(2, activation='softmax')(x) #B

# this is the model we will train
model = Model(input=base_model.input, output=predictions)

# first: train only the top layers (which were randomly initialized)
# i.e. freeze all convolutional InceptionV3 layers
for layer in base_model.layers:
    # layer.trainable = False
    layer.trainable = True

model.compile(optimizer=SGD(lr=0.001, momentum=0.9), loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy') #B

# train the model on the new data for a few epochs
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1. / 255,
    shear_range=0.2,
    zoom_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True)

# I changed flow_from_directory() a bit/
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    '.../train/',
    _mode='b-w',
    classes=['white','black'],
    follow_links=True,
    shuffle=True,
    target_size=(299, 299),
    batch_size=16,
    class_mode='binary')

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

# I changed flow_from_directory() a bit/
validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    '.../val/',
    _mode='train-val-test_b-w', _set='val',
    classes=['white', 'black'],
    target_size=(299, 299),
    batch_size=16,
    follow_links=True,
    class_mode='binary')

class LossHistory(Callback):
    def on_train_begin(self, logs={}):
        self.f = open('./history-log/log.txt', 'w')
        self.f.write('batch' + ' , ' + 'loss\n')

    def on_batch_end(self, batch, logs={}):
        self.f.write(str(logs.get('batch')) + ' , ' + str(logs.get('loss')) + '\n')

model_checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint('./saved_models/{epoch:02d}-{val_loss:.2f}.hdf5', monitor='val_loss', verbose=0, save_best_only=False, save_weights_only=False, mode='auto', period=1)
csv_logger = CSVLogger('./csv-log/log.csv', separator=',', append=False)
history = LossHistory()

from PIL import ImageFile
ImageFile.LOAD_TRUNCATED_IMAGES = True

model.fit_generator(
    train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch=733,
    epochs=1000,
    callbacks=[model_checkpoint, csv_logger, history],
    validation_data=validation_generator,
    verbose=1,
    validation_steps=706)
```

**Output:**

```
    Using TensorFlow backend.
    I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library libcublas.so.8.0 locally
    I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library libcudnn.so.5 locally
    I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library libcufft.so.8.0 locally
    I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library libcuda.so.1 locally
    I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library libcurand.so.8.0 locally
    W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE3 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
    W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.1 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
    W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.2 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
    W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use AVX instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
    I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:910] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
    I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:885] Found device 0 with properties:
    name: GeForce GTX TITAN
    major: 3 minor: 5 memoryClockRate (GHz) 0.8755
    pciBusID 0000:01:00.0
    Total memory: 5.94GiB
    Free memory: 5.75GiB
    I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:906] DMA: 0
    I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:916] 0: Y
    I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:975] Creating TensorFlow device (/gpu:0) -> (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX TITAN, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0)
    /patna/patna-codes/python/tensorlow-keras-test/finetune.py:27: UserWarning: Update your Model call to the Keras 2 API: Model(inputs=Tensor("in..., outputs=Tensor("de...)
    model = Model(input=base_model.input, output=predictions)
    Found 93792 images belonging to 2 classes.
    Found 90260 images belonging to 2 classes.
    Epoch 1/1000
    I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/pool_allocator.cc:247] PoolAllocator: After 2278 get requests, put_count=2134 evicted_count=1000 eviction_rate=0.468604 and unsatisfied allocation rate=0.546093
    I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/pool_allocator.cc:259] Raising pool_size_limit_ from 100 to 110
    9/733 [..............................] - ETA: 869s - loss: 0.7533I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/pool_allocator.cc:247] PoolAllocator: After 2286 get requests, put_count=2222 evicted_count=1000 eviction_rate=0.450045 and unsatisfied allocation rate=0.474628
    I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/pool_allocator.cc:259] Raising pool_size_limit_ from 233 to 256
    21/733 [..............................] - ETA: 646s - loss: 0.6912I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/pool_allocator.cc:247] PoolAllocator: After 2419 get requests, put_count=2718 evicted_count=1000 eviction_rate=0.367918 and unsatisfied allocation rate=0.312112
    I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/pool_allocator.cc:259] Raising pool_size_limit_ from 596 to 655
    732/733 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.4559/opt/keras-python3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/PIL/TiffImagePlugin.py:709: UserWarning: Corrupt EXIF data. Expecting to read 4 bytes but only got 0.
    warnings.warn(str(msg))
    /opt/keras-python3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/PIL/Image.py:885: UserWarning: Palette images with Transparency expressed in bytes should be converted to RGBA images
    'to RGBA images')
    733/733 [==============================] - 846s - loss: 0.4558 - val_loss: 0.2498
    Epoch 2/1000
    732/733 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.3979/opt/keras-python3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/PIL/TiffImagePlugin.py:709: UserWarning: Corrupt EXIF data. Expecting to read 4 bytes but only got 2.
    warnings.warn(str(msg))
    733/733 [==============================] - 844s - loss: 0.3977 - val_loss: 0.1956
    Epoch 3/1000
    733/733 [==============================] - 820s - loss: 0.3665 - val_loss: 0.2093
    Epoch 4/1000
    733/733 [==============================] - 819s - loss: 0.3549 - val_loss: 0.1918
    Epoch 5/1000
    732/733 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.3427Exception in thread Thread-6:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/lib/python3.4/threading.py", line 920, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
    File "/usr/lib/python3.4/threading.py", line 868, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
    File "/opt/keras-python3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 606, in data_generator_task
    generator_output = next(self._generator)
    File "/opt/keras-python3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/keras/preprocessing/image.py", line 756, in next
    return self.next(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/opt/keras-python3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/keras/preprocessing/image.py", line 1328, in next
    target_size=self.target_size)
    File "/opt/keras-python3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/keras/preprocessing/image.py", line 320, in load_img
    img = pil_image.open(path)
    File "/opt/keras-python3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 2439, in open
    im = _open_core(fp, filename, prefix)
    File "/opt/keras-python3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 2429, in _open_core
    im = factory(fp, filename)
    File "/opt/keras-python3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/PIL/JpegImagePlugin.py", line 761, in jpeg_factory
    im = JpegImageFile(fp, filename)
    File "/opt/keras-python3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/PIL/ImageFile.py", line 100, in init
    self._open()
    File "/opt/keras-python3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/PIL/JpegImagePlugin.py", line 332, in _open
    handler(self, i)
    File "/opt/keras-python3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/PIL/JpegImagePlugin.py", line 126, in APP
    dpi = x_resolution[0] / x_resolution[1]
    ZeroDivisionError: division by zero

    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/patna/patna-codes/python/tensorlow-keras-test/finetune.py", line 105, in
    validation_steps=706)
    File "/opt/keras-python3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/keras/legacy/interfaces.py", line 88, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/opt/keras-python3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1899, in fit_generator
    pickle_safe=pickle_safe)
    File "/opt/keras-python3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/keras/legacy/interfaces.py", line 88, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/opt/keras-python3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1985, in evaluate_generator
    str(generator_output))
    ValueError: output of generator should be a tuple (x, y, sample_weight) or (x, y). Found: None

    Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: It seems that you have an inappropriate image in your directory. Check if there is an empty image in your dataset.

Comment: Yes, you're right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found some corrupted images in dataset.

I noticed that steps_per_epoch=733 and validation_steps=706 were set for batch size 128 not 16, So all images are not given to the network and because of this the error doesn't occur in the first epoch.